How to detect the attachment or removal of Storage Device in Linux?
I am writing a C++ application for Linux where I want to detect that a user has attached or removed a storage device to the system and based on the event do something. How can this be achieved ?
I tried using the libudev library and was able to detect the same even though the documentation is not helpful at all. The documentation mentions that libudev is not suggested to be used in new projects and should be replaced with sd-device. From the documentation for sd-device I could not figure our how can I detect the above events.
One other solution I had explored was by monitoring the '/dev' folder but it doesn't seem to be a good option.
Any help will be appreciated.

How can this be achieved ? using the libudev library and was able to detect So you detected it and you ask how to do it? Yes, it is achieved using udev.

Most Linux software is open source, you can use that to study the code.

@KamilCuk, libudev is not suggested to be used for new projects and the replacement suggested has very poor documentation

I agree, the sd-device is lacking documentation. I rememeber I was reading systemd source code to do something with it. So use libudev or you could make an issue to systemd so they update the documentation.

You may need to listen to the UnitNew and UnitRemoved signals on the main Systemd DBus object and see if the name ends in ".device". Since Systemd creates a .device unit for block devices that are attached.
